# For loop not iterating properly and giving correct names

Tags: python

[image]

In the code, I want to print name of pharmacy and corresponding information in a dictionary.
I am webscraping, however everything works except the last loop.

You can use the the following two names and this would be your list g:
RITE AID OF OHIO INC,
ACME MARKETS INC

AS in the picture for two pharmacies, it's giving same information

```
g = []

for y in range(2):
    y = input('enter the name of pharmacies')
    g.append(y)


soupe = []
for text in g:
    url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text
    request_result=requests.get( url )
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text,"html.parser")
    soupe.append(soup)



C= {}
B=[]
for sup in soupe:
    heading_object=sup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'AVsepf'})
    for info in heading_object:
        A =(info.getText())
        B.append(A)    
        for name in g:
            C.update({name: B})
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your code during the last loop and seeing where your differs from your expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `A, B, C, g, y` mean nothing. You can use real names.

Secondly, your `B` list is being globally used across all search results, and then on the very last iteration of `for name in g`, you update **every** `name` to have the exact same instance of `B`.

---

Your code could significantly be simplified if you don't try to carry around global variables and extract out common functions.

```
def parse(search):
    url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + search  # this should be url-encoded
    request_result=requests.get( url )
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text,"html.parser")
    heading_object = soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'AVsepf'})
    return [x.getText() for x in heading_object]

results = {}

for _ in range(2):
    pharm = input('enter the name of a pharmacy')
    results[pharm] = parse(pharm)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(results)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
Can you help me with one last thing, can you help me understand the last return in under parse function, or simplify it so that I can understand it better

Comment: @user11644013 https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions